# firebaseui ios: don't show email sign in option

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have set sign in provider to only be Google:

```
providers = [FIRGoogleAuthUI()]
```

and yet when I launch, there is an email option in addition to google. Is the email option required?
[image]

Comment: Read https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy do you have a specific text selection from the repo? I looked there first but nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email provider can be disabled via flag `FUIAuth.signInWithEmailHidden`

Here is code example:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/samples/objc/FirebaseUI-demo-objc/Samples/Auth/FUIAuthViewController.m#L177